# Why my ubuntu freezes

Tags: freeze

I have ubuntu 14.04 lts and it's always freezes.When I wrote this message they froze 5 times.I have notebook with intel core i3,8gb ram and nvidia 740m.How to prevent it?

Comment: Can you tell us more details about what does `freeze` mean, in this case? You wait and system is back or you need to reboot it, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Firefox?  I get freezes when I do too much scrolling around and changing screens rapidly.  Also, I found out that if, when it first happens, I can hit AltCtrlDel and leave it for about 5 minutes and the computer logs me out.  I just sign back in and start over.

Comment: That's a mysterious answer. I would think that putting in more RAM would stop Firefox from freezing, either that or using a more lightweight desktop environment.